# How do I find all key bindings, global and application-specific, assigned in Lion?

Tags: macos, osx-lion

I was trying to use a specific key binding in Sublime Text 2, but the binding was triggering some other effect: fading the screen out, and then suddenly it reappears.

I eventually figured out the cause (LockTight, which activates the screensaver via a custom key binding), but this left me wondering whether there's some utility that can list all special key bindings, whether global or application-specific, in case I run into a similar problem.

Comment: [A similar question at Ask Different](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/56568/how-to-find-what-a-particular-keyboard-shortcut-does)

Answer (score 1):

I did this with a piece of software from the App Store called Cheat Sheet.  I think it's free.

Comment: I did not find this on the app store.

Comment: http://www.mediaatelier.com/CheatSheet/

Comment: seems that Cheat Sheet won't let me put in a particular key and figure out what app is taking it.